# How to run a job only before MR merge into master?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to implement a job that would be invoked only when a developer tries to merge the MR into master. How do I do that?

I tried using

```
only:
  - merge_requests
```

and it is almost what I need, except I don't want to run this job on every MR update - I want to run it only before merge into master.

I thought that maybe there is a way to use a new GitLab feature - [Pipelines for Merged Results](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/pipelines_for_merged_results/index.html) but as far as I understand I'd still need to run this job on every MR update.

Is there a way to do this that I'm missing? For example, can I only call this job for [Merge trains](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/pipelines_for_merged_results/merge_trains/index.html) - that would also be a solution?

Comment: gitlab can't tell when is the pipeline that runs before merge. at the merge point - the pipeline already has to pass. your option is to run it on every commit or after the merge (new pipeline for the merged branch)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
only:
   - master
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought about it, but in that case pipeline would only fail after the merge, right? That's the way I'd take if I can't find anything else, but I was hoping that a developer could press "Merge'" and that would invoke the pipeline with the job I want and merge the MR into master if it completes or aborts the merge if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

You would probably need to use the [advanced version of only](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#onlyexcept-advanced) and have something like:

```
only:
  refs:
    - merge_requests
  variables:
    - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"
```

In this case, it'll only run if both of these conditions are true since

> individual keys are logically joined by an AND

Comment: Thanks! But if I understand this correctly, with this setup my job will still activate on every update of my MR, not just when I perform the merge into master.

Comment: Sorry,  I think I may have misread what you were trying to achieve. If you only want it after the merge button has been pressed, then I would suggest what @bagerard has written in their answer, but it will not prevent the merge if the pipeline fails. That's the purpose of having it run when the MR is created.